# Give us a 'how many items are left' when filtering review queues

Tags: feature-request, review

> ### tl;dr Show us how many review items are left matching a filter.

With the unusually high number of items in the close vote review queue, it is kind of getting demoralizing to review them (which doesn't help!)

Why is it demoralizing? *You don't feel like you're making a difference!*

To combat this psychological problem with reviews, I suggest that we show, to the number, how many review items are left when filtering the queue.

For example, when I am reviewing close votes tagged with [xcode], it would be nice to see **exactly how many items are left - and see a reduction** when I cast that fifth vote on an item.

It would also make the big number on the /review page seem less huge. I could say, 'Hey! Only 445 Xcode items left! That's down from yesterday! *I can make a difference*!'

Ultimately, Stack Exchange operates on people wanting to help. If we can show people (or at least make them think) that they are making a difference, they will want to help more. Simple.

Comment: But would it be more demoralizing to find out the queue is growing faster than you're handling it?

Comment: @Fdinoff That's why you only show it when it's being filtered :)

Comment: Completely agree with this. I stopped even trying to do the close vote queue because it gives me very little sense of satisfaction; it feels like I'm not even making a dent. Giving *some* sort of positive progress indication would be enough to get me reviewing those again.